# input.value not obtaining/setting full string

Tags: php

i am struggling to get a whole string to be the value of an input tag

this is my code thus far but am not sure what is wrong with it

```
$message = "You have completed {$offername} [{$offerprovider}] and received {$offerpayout}";
echo "<input id='message' style='display: none;' value={$message}>$message</div>";
```

but when i check the value in javascript or something it just outputs the first word `You` any help would be appreciated as i am stuck

Comment: This is vague, but I dare say you want `value="$message">$message`...

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems in your code:

```
echo "<input id='message' style='display: none;' value={$message}>$message</div>";
```

The HTML generated by the line above looks like this:

```
<input id='message' style='display: none;' value=You have completed ...>
```

There are no quotes around the value of HTML attribute value. While the quotes are optional if the attribute value is a single word, they are needed when the value of the attribute contains many words; otherwise the value of attribute "value" is `You` and `have`, `completed` etc. are other HTML attributes of the `input` element.

The second problem of the code comes from the fact that you put some text there without correctly encoding the HTML special characters. For example, if the value of `$offername` is `O'Brian`, the generated HTML code (after the value of the `"value"` HTML attribute is correctly quoted) becomes:

```
<input id='message' style='display: none;' value='You have completed O'Brian [...] and received ...'>
```

and it is still invalid. Use the PHP function [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to properly encode the HTML special characters to get their literal value in the final HTML page.

Another minor notice (not a show stopper) is the quoting character. It's better to use quotes (`"`) for quoting of the attribute values in HTML. Apostrophes (`'`) are allowed but not recommended.

All in all, a better way to write the code is:

```
$message = "You have completed {$offername} [{$offerprovider}] and received {$offerpayout}";

$encodedMsg = htmlspecialchars($message);
printf('<input id="message" style="display: none;" value="%s">%s</div>',
    $encodedMsg, $encodedMsg);
```

Remember that everything you put in the HTML should be properly encoded or the browser might correct and interpret it in a different way than you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<input id='message' style='display: none;' value='{$message}'>$message</div>";
```

The attributes values must enclosed with single or double quotes otherwise it will split the text with space. it will print out like this.

```
<input id="message" style="display: none;" value="You" have="" completed="" and="" received="">
```

Comment: @Downvoter i would be glad if you specify the reason ?

Comment: Your answer is not correct until `$message` is either correctly escaped or defined as save (f.e. html and single quote free).

Comment: It does not mean it is not correct. it is not perfect.